# Quarkus mongodb and oraccle in same project

Tags: mongodb, oracle, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a project run with quarkus. if run with mode Dev will use Mongodb, and run with mode Dev2 will use Oracle. Database in Mongodb and Oracle have same table name, column name. Can i do that? please!

Comment: Why do you want to use mongo locally instead of another SQL database, you could use postgresql rather than mongo which is more similar to oracle

Comment: i want convert oracle to mongo, but now, system not aready yet, so i want run 2 enviroment

Comment: this is not a good idea, and its not possible use the same entities to support mongo in development and oracle in production because you are using panache you have to extend a different base class

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB and SQL databases didn't share the same API, so to do what you want you must create an interface layer and switch implementation at rutime.

For example, you can create an interface MyService and two implementation MongoMyService and OracleMyService.

What is challenging is to switch implementation at runtime as Quarkus only allows to switch beans at build time, so both beans must use a qualifier (`@Named` or `@Indentifier`) then at runtime you inject an `Instance<MyService>` and you programmatively select the instance you need based on a config property for example.

Something like (assuming your beans are qualified via `@Named`):

```
@ConfigProperty("myserver.impl") String myServerImpl;
@Inject Instance<MyService> myServiceInstance;
private MyService myService;

void init(@Observes StartupEvent startupEvent) {
    // select the right impl at runtime
    this.myService = myServiceInstance.select(NamedLitteral.of(myServerImpl)).get();
}
```

As @javier-toja suggested, this would be easier to switch between Oracle and another SQL database (like Postgres or H2) as you'll be able to share the same impl and only switch using JDBC URL and driver.

Comment: how can i get result from function in myservice, mongoservice return mongoentity and oracle return jpaentity?

Comment: You need to use a DTO to map the MongoEntity and the JpaEntity to a common type.